# Tweaking Biblatex-chicago citation format

Tags: biblatex, xetex, hyperref, polyglossia

I'm hoping this hasn't been asked elsewhere already; if so, I apologize.

My issue is that I am trying to format my dissertation using Chicago style (biblatex-chicago). I am using XeLaTeX + polyglossia for ancient Greek text, if that helps (yet it's not particularly important for the issue at hand). Chicago style has worked fine overall, yet I need to follow the style of a particular journal for my citations.

Here's a sample from my BibLaTeX .bib file:

```
@BOOK{WIngram80,
  title = {Sophocles: {A}n {I}nterpretation},
  publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
  year = {1980},
  author = {Winnington-Ingram, R. P.},
  address = {Cambridge}
}
```

Here is how I'm calling BibLaTeX in my .tex file: `\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}`

Biblatex-chicago formats citations as such:

Input: `See \textcite[120]{WIngram80}`

Output: See Winnington-Ingram (1980, 120)

I need to format it like this: See Winnington-Ingram (1980) 120.

Otherwise, the journal I'm using works with Chicago style, except for in-text citations. Citations without page numbers work fine, i.e., "Winnington-Ingram (1980)" -- but I'd like to fix this issue, hopefully with \textcite at the very least.

Also, I need to retain the date in parentheses even within parenthetical citations (i.e., \parencite), so an output of `\parencite[120]{WIngram80}` should be: "(Winnington-Ingram (1980) 120)"

Let me know if you need any other information.
Thanks very much in advance!

** EDIT: Thank you Moewe, your suggestions worked beautifully! I have a couple of other questions on formatting, mostly with regard to hyperref, but they are germane to this discussion as well.

When I use \textcite with a page number or other reference argument, I'd like to have both the last name and the date hyperlinked; the page is unimportant. While this works just fine for \footcite, if I am using \textcite in a footnote with other information, like so:

`\footnote{See \textcite[78]{Vernant}. The French translation is my own.}`

The output is: See Vernant (**1977**) 78. The French translation is my own. (I'm using **bold** to indicate where the link occurs here)

I'd prefer it to be: See **Vernant (1977)** 78. The French translation is my own.

I'm not sure if this is possible, but it works perfectly like this with `\footcite`, if the footnote needs nothing other than the citation.

Input: `\footcite[See][218]{Barfield}`

Output: See **Barfield (1988)** 218.

I have detailed footnotes here and there with text citations and other commentary, and above all I would like to keep things consistent, especially with hyperlinks. The editorial office is known for being fairly strict about these things, so I want to make sure to keep it all uniform.

Thanks again for your help moewe!

** edit: I realized that I forgot to mention some other patches I collected to help with hyperref support:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{citehyperref}{%
\DeclareFieldAlias{bibhyperref}{noformat}% Avoid nested links
\bibhyperref{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{textcitehyperref}{%
  \DeclareFieldAlias{bibhyperref}{noformat}% Avoid nested links
  \bibhyperref{%
  #1%
\ifbool{cbx:parens}
  {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
  {}}}

\savebibmacro{cite}
\savebibmacro{textcite}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \printtext[citehyperref]{%
  \restorebibmacro{cite}%
  \usebibmacro{cite}}}

\renewbibmacro*{textcite}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    ( not test {\iffieldundef{prenote}} and
       test {\ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}} )
    or
    ( not test {\iffieldundef{postnote}} and
       test {\ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{\value{citetotal}}} )
}
{\DeclareFieldAlias{textcitehyperref}{noformat}}
{}%
  \printtext[textcitehyperref]{%
  \restorebibmacro{textcite}%
  \usebibmacro{textcite}}}
```

I came across that snippet, and I'm not sure how it affects a possible solution, if at all. Sorry for not mentioning that before.

Comment: Mhhhh, interestingly, when I ran my MWE below, the only thing to be hyperlinked in any of the `\...cite` commands was the year (that is, the author name was never highlighted).

Comment: See the edits above. I know this has gotten a little hacky, as a result, but I've been trying to make this work with a template that was originally using BibTeX, so I've had to do some changes here and there.

Comment: I have edited my post to incorporate the hyperlink fixes (I have not documented them though, I hope you are okay with that). Let me know if it woks.

Comment: Moewe, everything looks great now. Can't thank you enough! I very much appreciate the help, and I'm hoping that the document will pass with flying colors (it should!).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`biblatex-chicago` actually goes through quite great length to achieve the output you get.

The following modifications undoes the behaviour of adding the postnote to the parentheses

```
\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addspace}
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{textcite:postnote}{%
  \ifbool{cbx:parens}%
    {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}%
    {}%
  \iffieldundef{postnote}%
    {}%
    {\savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lastyear}%
     \setunit{\postnotedelim}%
     \printfield{postnote}}%
  \ifthenelse{\value{multicitecount}=\value{multicitetotal}}%
    {}%
    {\textcitedelim}}% Not \multicitedelim ???
\makeatother
```

The old version from `chicago-authordate.cbx` had the `\bibcloseparen` part at the end of the macro, resulting in the closing parentheses *after* the postnote.

To always have the year in parentheses (even in `\parencite`), we have to redefine the `cite` bibmacro. Since the standard `parens` field format in `biblatex` will use square brackets `[]` within nested parentheses, we also have to define a simpler version of that format to always use parentheses - regardless of the nesting-level.

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{parenshc}{(#1)}
\makeatletter
\newbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}%
  {\iffieldequalstr{entrysubtype}{classical}% Similar to notes+bib
    {\iffieldundef{shorthand}%
      {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR
          \ifentrytype{inreference}\OR
          \ifentrytype{reference}\OR
          \ifentrytype{mvreference}}% Simplified for CMS
        {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
          \setunit{\addspace}%
          \usebibmacro{cite:reinit}}
        {\iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}%
          {\iffieldundef{postnote}%
            {\setunit{\compcitedelim}}%
            {}%
            \usebibmacro{cite:label}}
          {\iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lastyear}%
            {}%
            {\usebibmacro{cmsbracketname}% For names in []
              \ifentrytype{customc}%
              {\newcunit}%
              {\setunit{\addspace}}}%
            \usebibmacro{cite:label}%
            \iffieldundef{postnote}%
            {\savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}%
            {\savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lastyear}}}}}%
      {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand+title}}}
    {\iffieldundef{shorthand}%
      {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR
          \ifentrytype{inreference}\OR
          \ifentrytype{reference}\OR
          \ifentrytype{mvreference}}% Simplified for CMS
        {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
          \setunit{\addspace}%
          \printtext[parenshc]{\usebibmacro{cmscitesortdate}}%
          \usebibmacro{cite:reinit}}
        {\iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}%
          {\iffieldundef{postnote}%
            {\setunit{\compcitedelim}}%
            {}%
            \printtext[parenshc]{\usebibmacro{cmscitesortdate}}}
          {\iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lastyear}% Is this right?
            {}%
            {\usebibmacro{cmsbracketname}%
              \setunit{\nameyeardelim}}%
            \printtext[parenshc]{\usebibmacro{cmscitesortdate}}%
            \iffieldundef{postnote}%
            {\savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}%
            {\savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lastyear}}}}}%
      {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}}%
  \setunit{\multicitedelim}}% ???
\makeatother
```

This modification will cause the standard `\cite` to have the year in parentheses as well, I'm not sure whether that's what you wanted, but it would get quite messy if we took care of that as well.

MWE

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{parenshc}{(#1)}
\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addspace}
\makeatletter
\newbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}%
  {\iffieldequalstr{entrysubtype}{classical}% Similar to notes+bib
    {\iffieldundef{shorthand}%
      {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR
          \ifentrytype{inreference}\OR
          \ifentrytype{reference}\OR
          \ifentrytype{mvreference}}% Simplified for CMS
        {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
          \setunit{\addspace}%
          \usebibmacro{cite:reinit}}
        {\iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}%
          {\iffieldundef{postnote}%
            {\setunit{\compcitedelim}}%
            {}%
            \usebibmacro{cite:label}}
          {\iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lastyear}%
            {}%
            {\usebibmacro{cmsbracketname}% For names in []
              \ifentrytype{customc}%
              {\newcunit}%
              {\setunit{\addspace}}}%
            \usebibmacro{cite:label}%
            \iffieldundef{postnote}%
            {\savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}%
            {\savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lastyear}}}}}%
      {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand+title}}}
    {\iffieldundef{shorthand}%
      {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR
          \ifentrytype{inreference}\OR
          \ifentrytype{reference}\OR
          \ifentrytype{mvreference}}% Simplified for CMS
        {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
          \setunit{\addspace}%
          \printtext[parenshc]{\usebibmacro{cmscitesortdate}}%
          \usebibmacro{cite:reinit}}
        {\iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}%
          {\iffieldundef{postnote}%
            {\setunit{\compcitedelim}}%
            {}%
            \printtext[parenshc]{\usebibmacro{cmscitesortdate}}}
          {\iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lastyear}% Is this right?
            {}%
            {\usebibmacro{cmsbracketname}%
              \setunit{\nameyeardelim}}%
            \printtext[parenshc]{\usebibmacro{cmscitesortdate}}%
            \iffieldundef{postnote}%
            {\savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}%
            {\savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lastyear}}}}}%
      {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}}%
  \setunit{\multicitedelim}}% ???

\renewbibmacro*{textcite:postnote}{%
  \ifbool{cbx:parens}%
    {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}%
    {}%
  \iffieldundef{postnote}%
    {}%
    {\savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lastyear}%
     \setunit{\postnotedelim}%
     \printfield{postnote}}%
  \ifthenelse{\value{multicitecount}=\value{multicitetotal}}%
    {}%
    {\textcitedelim}}% Not \multicitedelim ???
\makeatother
\begin{document}
  As was discovered \textcite[210]{cicero} and \textcite[210]{wilde} \parencite[210]{cicero} and \cite[210]{wilde}.

  \textcite{wilde,cicero} vs \parencite{wilde,cicero}.

  \textcite{baez/article,wilde,cicero} vs \parencite{baez/article,wilde,cicero}.

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

To incorporate your hyperlink fixes try the following MWE. Note that you will not have to add any other hyperlink code to this snippet. I have incorporated the code you posted in your update into this version.

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{parenshc}{(#1)}
\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addspace}
\makeatletter
\newbibmacro*{cite}{\printtext[citehyperref]{%
  \ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}%
  {\iffieldequalstr{entrysubtype}{classical}% Similar to notes+bib
    {\iffieldundef{shorthand}%
      {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR
          \ifentrytype{inreference}\OR
          \ifentrytype{reference}\OR
          \ifentrytype{mvreference}}% Simplified for CMS
        {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
          \setunit{\addspace}%
          \usebibmacro{cite:reinit}}
        {\iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}%
          {\iffieldundef{postnote}%
            {\setunit{\compcitedelim}}%
            {}%
            \usebibmacro{cite:label}}
          {\iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lastyear}%
            {}%
            {\usebibmacro{cmsbracketname}% For names in []
              \ifentrytype{customc}%
              {\newcunit}%
              {\setunit{\addspace}}}%
            \usebibmacro{cite:label}%
            \iffieldundef{postnote}%
            {\savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}%
            {\savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lastyear}}}}}%
      {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand+title}}}
    {\iffieldundef{shorthand}%
      {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR
          \ifentrytype{inreference}\OR
          \ifentrytype{reference}\OR
          \ifentrytype{mvreference}}% Simplified for CMS
        {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
          \setunit{\addspace}%
          \printtext[parenshc]{\usebibmacro{cmscitesortdate}}%
          \usebibmacro{cite:reinit}}
        {\iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}%
          {\iffieldundef{postnote}%
            {\setunit{\compcitedelim}}%
            {}%
            \printtext[parenshc]{\usebibmacro{cmscitesortdate}}}
          {\iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lastyear}% Is this right?
            {}%
            {\usebibmacro{cmsbracketname}%
              \setunit{\nameyeardelim}}%
            \printtext[parenshc]{\usebibmacro{cmscitesortdate}}%
            \iffieldundef{postnote}%
            {\savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}%
            {\savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lastyear}}}}}%
      {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}}%
  \setunit{\multicitedelim}}}% ???

\renewbibmacro*{textcite:postnote}{%
  \ifbool{cbx:parens}%
    {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}%
    {}%
  \iffieldundef{postnote}%
    {}%
    {\savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lastyear}%
     \setunit{\postnotedelim}%
     \printfield{postnote}}%
  \ifthenelse{\value{multicitecount}=\value{multicitetotal}}%
    {}%
    {\textcitedelim}}% Not \multicitedelim ???


\DeclareFieldFormat{citehyperref}{%
\DeclareFieldAlias{bibhyperref}{noformat}% Avoid nested links
\bibhyperref{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{textcitehyperref}{%
  \DeclareFieldAlias{bibhyperref}{noformat}% Avoid nested links
  \bibhyperref{%
  #1%
\ifbool{cbx:parens}
  {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
  {}}}

\renewbibmacro*{textcite}{%
  \iftoggle{cms@los}%
  {\printtext[textcitehyperref]{\usebibmacro{textcite:authshort}}}%
  {\printtext[textcitehyperref]{\usebibmacro{textcite:citeshort}}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  As\footcite[See][]{knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b} was discovered \textcite[210]{cicero} and \textcite[210]{wilde} \parencite[210]{cicero} and \cite[210]{wilde}.

  \textcite{wilde,cicero} vs \parencite{wilde,cicero}.\footcite{wilde}

  \textcite{baez/article,wilde,cicero} vs \parencite{baez/article,wilde,cicero}.

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```